# AWS Cloudformation getting error when using Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Can you please check the code I created using `YAML` for `Cloudformation` for some strange reason I am getting the below error. Sorry for the code alignment.

```
Error: CREATE_FAILED    AWS::EC2::Instance  Ec2InstanceOne  The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: a4018f68-7454-4f1f-ba81-6ec3b3c78d98)
```

---

```
Resources:
Ec2InstanceOne:
Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
  AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a
  ImageId: ami-466768ac
  InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: terminate #stop or Terminate
  InstanceType: t2.micro
  KeyName: Resources # If we are mentioning in Parameters we have to mention 
  AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName


  SecurityGroups:
    - !Ref Ec2SecurityGroup
  SubnetId: !Ref MySubnet

Ec2SecurityGroup:
Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
Properties:
  GroupDescription: This is to allow HTTP site access
  VpcId: !Ref MyVpc
  SecurityGroupIngress:
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 80
      ToPort: 80
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 22
      ToPort: 22
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

MyVpc:
Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
Properties:
CidrBlock: 192.168.0.0/16

MyRoute:
Type: AWS::EC2::Route
Properties:
RouteTableId: 10.120.0.0/16
DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
InstanceId: !Ref Ec2InstanceOne

MySubnet:
Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
Properties:
AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a
CidrBlock: 192.168.1.0/24
VpcId: !Ref MyVpc
```

Comment: Did you try to use 'security-group-ids' instead of 'SecurityGroups'? As in https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2453

Comment: Many thanks @DavidWinder, it working now it was my mistake clearly.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the SubnetId for an instance, you should use the Security Group ID instead of the Security Group Name. Just replace SecurityGroups by SecurityGroupIds in the EC2 instance section.

Reference:

1. [reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684238/aws-cfn-error-the-parameter-groupname-cannot-be-used-with-the-parameter-subnet)
2. [Reference2](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2453#issuecomment-281840723)
3. [Reference3](https://acloud.guru/forums/intro-aws-cloudformation/discussion/-LKQzttlrIVPu2Zvvm1E/error-the-parameter-groupname-cannot-be-used-with-the-parameter-subnet?answer=-LQnurDjbs9kUnL-CCnr)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while working on systems manager Documents. We need to use a security groups ID instead of a security group name.

Replace this

```
 SecurityGroups:
    - !Ref Ec2SecurityGroup
```

with this, and try. It will fix the issue.

```
SecurityGroupIds:
  - !Ref Ec2SecurityGroupID
```

Security-group name is only for default VPC or EC2-classic. For non-default VPC subnets we have to use security group IDs.